# Why does "git checkout <filename>" only work for non-staged files?

Tags: git, git-checkout

If I commit and then make changes to a file `foo`, I can undo these changes by `git checkout foo`. If I make changes to `foo` AND add them with `git add foo`, then `git checkout foo` doesn't do anything (and doesn't say anything)

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: I think that if a file is already saved in a commit you are supposed to checkout the commit.

Comment: The answers you have now are correct, but the key insight here is that there are not one, not two, but *three* active versions of any one file at all times: one in the current or `HEAD` commit, one in the index, and one in the work-tree. `git checkout` copies *to* the work-tree, but it can copy *from* either of the other two, or in fact from any other commit as well. There's one more oddity: copying *from* any commit at all (`HEAD` or not) writes to *both* the index *and* the work-tree, replacing *both* versions. The *why* answer to this is mostly "because that was easy to implement."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
git checkout foo
```

without additional arguments, you're telling git to replace the `foo` in your worktree with the `foo` in your index.  So if you've `add`ed (i.e. staged, i.e. *updated the index with*) all the changes to `foo`, then of course there's nothing for this `checkout` command to do.

The normal procedure to back out the change would be to first `reset` (update the index from the `HEAD` commit) and *then* use `checkout` to update the working version.

Then again, you *can* use `checkout` to get the version of `foo` from the previous commit

```
git checkout HEAD foo
```

This works just as well; the two-step approach is probably just a bit more widely known since it uses commands suggested by `git status` for un-staging and un-doing changes.

Comment: I'm confused that you say the normal procedure is two steps when checkout actually can do what I want in one step. What is the disadvantage of the checkout solution then?

Comment: There is no disadvantage. It's just that the git UI happens to recommend commands that each only do one of the two steps, so out of habit even when I need to do both I (and I think many users) tend to use the two-command approach.  Clarified this point a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can unstage it and then check it out :)

```
git reset <file>

git checkout <file>
```

The reason behind not checking them out as well is because if you change your files locally and then want to update to the master branch in example, your work and staged files should be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.23 (August 2019), you now can avoid using the [confusing `git checkout` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) (which deals with files or branches), and the new (still experimental) [`git restore` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

> You can restore both the index and the working tree (this the same as using `git-checkout`)

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
```

> or the short form which is more practical but less readable:

```
git restore -s@ -SW hello.c
```

That will restore both working tree *and* staging area (cache).